# 502 Bad gateway while using nginx server

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine, bigchaindb

I am following https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/v2.0.0b9/docs/server/source/simple-deployment-template/set-up-nginx.md

I have Added SSL certificate to bleocean.com
and it was redirecting to my NGINX server page when i was reaching https://bleocean.com.

When I updated NGINX.config file to contents of https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf and did chenges as directed

It is now showing 502 Bad Gateway when i go to https://bleocean.com

I tried on local machine as well as on google cloud each time when I update config file it shows 502 bad gateway. Please suggest if I am making any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because there is no application running on the port 9984. Check if  MongoDB, BigchainDB and Tendermint are running. Please add the logs of your `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.